# Export all users' data from Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

According to [this article](https://support.google.com/a/answer/100458?hl=en), as a super admin, I should be able to export data for all users. However, when I visit https://admin.google.com/ac/customertakeout, I am presented with the following screen:

[image]

I have confirmed that:

- My account is a super admin.
- My account is over 30 days old.
- My account has 2-step verification enabled
- My organization has less than 1,000 users

Why can I not export data?

Answer (score 2):

While posting I noticed two tiny words "and enforced".

> You must have 2-step verification enabled and enforced on your account

It was enabled, but not enforced.

Once I enforced 2FA for the org, I was able to see the "START EXPORT" button.